# Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and let $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation. Show that $T$ is one-to-one iff T is onto.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I started this proof by supposing $T$ is not onto. This then implies that $T$ can be inconsistent ie; $T(x) = b$ can have no solution. However, $T$ being onto requires that $T(x) = 0$ has the trivial solution, directly contradicting the first portion.

Is there something else to this proof? I feel that I'm skipping something & have to do more with it (Besides the vice-versa part for an iff proof).

Comment: Not sure who uses "inconsistent" to mean that. Very odd terminology, in my experience.

Comment: **Hint:** $\text{dim}V = \text{dim} \ker T + \dim \text{im}T$

Comment: I get it you are trying to show that if $T$ is not onto then it is not one to one, I think that is one half of what you need, but I don't think that half has been done properly :'(

Comment: It's from my textbook. What do you usually see?

Comment: "However, $T$ being onto requires that $T(x)=0$ has the trivial solution" Actually, the trivial solution $x = 0$ is present for *all* linear maps, not just ones that are (or aren't) onto. On the other hand, one-to-one maps have **only** the trivial solution, meaning that $T(x) \neq 0$ if $x \neq 0$.

Comment: @SultanHall Usually one sees "inconsistent" referring to a system of linear equations: $Ax = b$, where $A$ is some fixed matrix, and $x, b$ are column vectors, with $x$ an unknown. One could naturally generalise to $T$ being a linear map between abstract vector spaces, $x$ being an unknown vector in the domain, and $b$ being a vector in the codomain. But, it's unusual to see someone refer to the operator $T$ *itself* as "inconsistent" (we would say it's not surjective). This is because $Tx = b$ can be a consistent equation, depending on $b$ (e.g., as you noted, when $b = 0$).

Comment: *Avoiding rank-nullity theorem*: Consider a basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ for $V$. Assuming that $T$ is 1-to-1, show that $Tv_1,\dots,Tv_n$ are linearly independent, and conclude that $T$ is onto. Assuming that $T$ is onto, show that $Tv_1,\dots,Tv_n$ spans $V$, and conclude that $T$ is 1-to-1.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you have proved nothing.

If $T$ is not onto, there is a $b\in V$ such that $T(x)=b$ has no solution. The fact that $T(x)=0$ has a solution provides no contradiction (the system $T(x)=0$ has a solution for every linear $T$).

You *must* use the fact that $V$ is finite dimensional, because otherwise the statement is false: it's easy to provide examples of

- $T\colon V\to V$ which is one-to-one but not onto, or
- $T\colon V\to V$ which is onto but not one-to-one

if you don't assume that $V$ is finite dimensional. Take as $V$ the set of sequences with the obvious operations. Now consider
$$
T\colon (a_0,a_1,\dotsc)\mapsto(0,a_0,a_1,\dotsc)
$$
which is one-to-one but not onto, or
$$
T\colon (a_0,a_1,\dotsc)\mapsto(a_1,a_2,\dotsc)
$$
which is onto but not one-to-one.

Suppose now $V$ is finite dimensional.

If $T$ is one-to-one, take a basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$. Then $\{T(v_1),\dots,T(v_n)\}$ is linearly independent: what if it's not a basis?

If $T$ is onto, take a basis $\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ and choose $v_i$ such that $T(v_i)=w_i$, for $i=1,2,\dots,n$. What if $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is not a basis?